# Angularjs [$rootScope:inprog] inprogress error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-scope

I am getting angularjs  [$rootScope:inprog] error.

`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest`.

this is the function calling

```
 Members.get({}, function (response) { // success
   $scope.family_mem = response.data;    
  }, function (error) { // ajax loading error

    Data.errorMsg(); // display error notification
  });
```

in console i am getting results  by php controller function.but not updating `$scope.family_mem` instead going to error part.
this is the directive

```
myApp.directive('mySelect', function() {
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element){
      $(element).select2();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I think you are using minified angularjs source code. Try using `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` which will give detailed info about the error.

Comment: when using angular.js getting digest in progress error

Answer (score 35):

Usually this means that you defined $rootScope.$apply somewhere manually inside of the another angular code which has lifecycle already. This should not be happen in common cases as angular tracks the lifecycle itself. The one common case where it is needed is when you need to update scope from non-angular code (like jquery or old-fashioned js stuff). So please check if you have this somewhere. In case you really need it's better to use safe apply (the common code snippet):

```
angular.module('main', []).service('scopeService', function() {
     return {
         safeApply: function ($scope, fn) {
             var phase = $scope.$root.$$phase;
             if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                 if (fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
                     fn();
                 }
             } else {
                 $scope.$apply(fn);
             }
         },
     };
});
```

Then you can inject this service and make necessary calling by:

```
scopeService.safeApply($rootScope, function() {
    // you code here to apply the changes to the scope
});
```

Comment: no error is shown for a particular amount of data in database. after the limits it shows the error

Comment: Ok. I guess the problem can be with the server side but the error you mentioned is another error when you handle the logic? Where the error occured? At Data.errorMsg()? Somewhere else?

Comment: i dont know where the inprogress error is occuring. but Data.errorMsg() shows another error which is custom.

Comment: You should better debug this and at least understand where it happens so we can help you. Otherwise jsfiddle would be good. Also what is the actual problem for you - this angular error or the problem that the data fails when going from the server?

Comment: i guess $scope.family_mem is using in a typeahead. thats y in progress error

Comment: Simple setting of a scope variable should not cause such error. It doesn't call itself either $digest or $apply.

Comment: i am also get error Error: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object .i dont know whether i is related to inprogress error

Comment: rootScope is not available

Answer (score 7):

[$rootScope:inprog] inprogress error in my case:
**Case 1:** It means you're executing two actions at a time.

**Example:**

```
goView();
hidePopOver(); //Will trigger error
```

Use **$timeout** to make sure two actions (function) are not running at the same time.

```
goView();
$timeout(function () {
    hidePopOver();
}, 300);
```

**Case 2**: an action has not executed completely.
Use $timeout to make sure first action has executed.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $(element.target).trigger('click');
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but the `time delay` resolved my issue like a charm.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $(element.target).trigger('click');
}, 300);
```

If the trigger is on jquery/javascript side.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(element.target).trigger('click');
}, 300);
```