# angularJS controller doesn't load the first time

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope

Inside the view, I am declaring:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div ng-if="authenticated=='no'">
        <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="authenticated=='yes'">
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the angular file that contains the controller is properly called before the code lines above.

Inside my controller, I am trying to load data from a node api, with an `$http` get request and set its result to the scope like follow:

```
var indexModule = angular.module ('indexModule', []);

indexModule.controller('LoginController',['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/api/data')
      .success(function(data){
          $scope.authenticated = data.authenticated;
      })
      .error(function(){
            alert('Error occured');
      });
```

This works only after several page refreshes. Is there something I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here are the node.js routes:

```
app.get('/api/data', function (req,res) { // this is called by the controller to populate $scope
    var sendtoFront = new Object();
    toFront.authenticated = req.isAuthenticated() ? 'yes' : 'no';
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        toFront.session = req.session.passport;
    }
    res.send(toFront);
});
app.get('/', function (req,res) { // this load the view 
    res.render('index'); 
});
```

**UPDATE II**

I tried the same code in Firefox instead of chrome and it seems to be working correctly any ideas about how to repair this.

Comment: does console giving any error? code looks fine.

Comment: do you have the <scripts> in the correct order? 1. angular.js, 2. your controller.js?

Comment: no errors are return by console

Comment: @satchcoder yes the scripts are in the correct order

Comment: On the initial response, is data being returned?  Can you see your response data if you inspect the page and look at the response tab in Chrome?

Comment: explain what happens when it doesn't work and is request being made? Not much debugging information given

Comment: can u share the route config and the html action from where you are getting routed here.. problem would mostly be you are specifying it twice somewhere

Comment: @Cognitronic  No nothing is returned, because the $http.get() that is supposed to give a response is not triggered.

Comment: @charlietfl No the request is not being made

Comment: I bet my head that you have `$scope.apply` in process and this code alone is not cosing any problems

Comment: @maurycy yes i added $scope.apply after RahulB proposition but it didn't help

Comment: can you make a working plunker with reproduced error?

Comment: Now after reading comments again I can tell for sure, there is nothing wrong with this controller, the problem exists before it's even initialised, do you have `$scope.$digest` or `$scope.apply` in any other place?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : After reading error in console, it doesn't seem you want $scope.$apply().
It seems you have manually called $apply() from $rootscope.
Check in other portions of code if you have manually called $apply on $rootScope.

Similar issue :[Angularjs [$rootScope:inprog] inprogress error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733422/angularjs-rootscopeinprog-inprogress-error)

Comment: `$http` runs `digest` cycle internally, no need to do `$scope.$apply()`, it will throw an error in console. `apply already in progress`

Comment: `$apply()` isn't used inside `$http`

Comment: I  think that the apply must be done. RahulB is right.

Comment: this is so bad example of `$apply` it hurts my eyes, `$apply` should be used when you do something OUTSIDE angular model to actually inform angular that something changed and `$digest` is required, `$scope.authenticated = 'something'` will be enough to queue for `$digest`