# Angular Js $scope.$apply doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form through which i am adding the data. Same is the case for data update. I populate form by getting data against a particular id via $http post. I have changed the scope variables but not getting modified values. Here are my efforts :

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" ng-model="formData.formType" ng-init="formData.formType = submit_button" value="{{submit_button}}"/>

<input type="hidden" name="student_id" ng-model="formData.studentId" ng-init="formData.studentId = student_id" value="{{student_id}}"/>

$scope.Edit = function (id) {
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                data: $.param({action: 'fetch', id: id}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (response) {
                if (!response.success) {
                    alert("something went wronge");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $scope.formData = response.data;
                    $scope.student_id = response.data.id;
                    $scope.submit_button = 'Update';
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            });
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Top answer on this post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733422/angularjs-rootscopeinprog-inprogress-error

Comment: But why do you need to call the `$scope.$apply()`? The digest cycle get triggered automatically, why do you trigger it manually?

Comment: @iulian because after changing scope variables of hidden fields, not getting updated values in post data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of the safe apply in the scope.

```js
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};


$scope.safeApply(function() {
  alert('Now I'm wrapped for protection!');
});
```